# $P$ is a point on a hyperbola whose focal points are $F_1$ and $F_2$. $Q$ on the line that bisects $\angle F_1PF_2$. Prove $|PF_1-PF_2|>|QF_1-QF_2|$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, conic-sections

$\require{cancel}$
Sorry for the grammatical mistake in the title; it was needed to keep the title under 150 characters.

$P$ is a point on a hyperbola whose focal points are $F_1$ and $F_2$. $Q$ is on the line that bisects $\angle F_1PF_2$. Prove $|PF_1-PF_2|>|QF_1-QF_2|$. This means that line $\overline{PQ}$ only intersects the hyperbola in one place - at $P$.

What I've tried is drawing the ellipse which has focal points $F_1$ and $F_2$ which intersects $P$ and drawing the tangent line, but I'm not really sure where to go from here.

I'd prefer a geometric solution over an algebraic, but either are fine.

---

**EDIT: Ignore this, I messed up**

> EDIT: I've have a solution, but I never used the bisector fact. Can
>   you check it for me?
>
> $QP+PF_1>QF_1$, by triangle inequality. Therefore, $PF_1>QF_1-QP$.
>
> $QP+PF_2>QF_2$, by triangle inequality. Therefore, $PF_2>QF_2-QP$.
>
> Subtracting these two equations, I get:
>
> $$ PF_1-PF_2>QF_1-QP-(QF_2-QP) $$ 
>   $$ PF_1-PF_2>QF_1-QF_2-\cancel{QP}+\cancel{QP} $$ 
>   $$ PF_1-PF_2>QF_1-QF_2$$
>
> Where do the absolute values come in? And why did I not need to use
>   the fact that $\overline{PQ}$ bisects $\angle F_1PF_2$? Do I add the
>   absolute values in $PF_1>|QF_1-QP|$ because I'm dealing with
>   magnitudes, resulting in $|PF_1-PF_2|>|QF_1-QF_2| $?
>
> ---
>
> EDIT: Changed G to Q

Comment: The line that bisects $\widehat{F_1 P F_2}$ *is* the tangent line. It is the only thing you need to prove.

Comment: I'm trying to prove that that line is the tangent line by proving that $|PF_1-PF_2|>|QF_1-QF_2|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the mirror image $F_1^*$ of $F_1$ with respect to the line that bisects $\widehat{F_1 P F_2}$.

Then obviously $PF_1=PF_1^*$ and $QF_1=QF_1^*$, but $P,F_2,F_1^*$ are collinear, while $Q,F_2,F_1^*$ are not. The triangular inequality now gives your claim.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have any ideas why my proof (which I added in the question) is wrong? It doesn't use the fact that $\angle F_1PF_2$ is bisected by $\overline{PQ}$.

Comment: I cannot understand what is $G$.

Comment: However, in general, $a<b$ and $c<d$ do not imply $a-c < b-d$. You cannot subtract inequalities.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll fix it.